# Observable.zip chooses different schedulers to subscribe on different calls

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I have two observables o1 and o2. I zip them over Observable.zip() function, but subscription is every time on different scheduler. I expect all of o1, o2 and z observable should be subscribed on Schedulers.io() observable. But it is random either Schedulers.io() or Schedulers.computation() every time.

Here is my source code to reproduce the problem

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class RxZipSchedulers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            Observable<String> o1 = Observable.just("o1").subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
            Observable<String> o2 = Observable.just("o2");

            Observable z = Observable.zip(o1, o2, (s1, s2) -> s1 + " " + s2 + " " + Thread.currentThread());

            z.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(res -> {
                        System.out.println(res);
                    });

            z.toCompletable().await();
        }
    }

}
```

On my machine the output is like that (note either RxComputationScheduler or RxIoScheduler every time):

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-1,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-4,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-1,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-3,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-4,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-3,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxIoScheduler-3,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-1,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxComputationScheduler-3,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxIoScheduler-3,5,main]

o1 o2 Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]

Why all of o1, o2, z observables don't subscribe on Schedulers.io() ? I thought that this scheduler should be propagated over the whole chain of observables, but that's happen only sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

What's happens with `zip()` operator is, that the zip function will be invoked on the thread (according to the `Scheduler`) of the last emitting `Observable`, that is, in this case, randomly `o1` and `o2` Schedulers that are `computation()` and `io()` and .

Why are the Schedulers for each is `computation()` and `io()`?
Although you've specified the Scheduler in the zip `Observable`, it just affecting the subscription operation of the `zip()`, which don't affect necessarily where each zipped `Observable` acts.

In RxJava each `Observable` can specify its own `Scheduler`, and when the `zip(`) will subscribe to the zipped `Observable`, each will operate on the configured `Scheduler`:
in the `o1` case - `computation` as it was configured explicitly with `subscribeOn()`.
**But**, if no `Scheduler` is specified for `Observable`- then the Observable will act on the `Scheduler` that subscription was done - in your case that's what's happens at `o2`, as its subscription invoked where zip subscription invoked - `io()`.

If you do care for some reason where the `zip()` function happens, you can simply carry on the 2 zipped objects, and with `observerOn()` change where you operate and perform your custom zip logic with `map()`.